# How can I access component state in DragSource Specification

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I have a component that maintain a list of objects in a State. I intend to make this component a Drag Source. When the Drag event begins, I wish to drag the list of objects in component state. 
The problem is that Drag Source Spec object's method beginDrag takes the component's prop as an argument. This means that object that can be dragged must be derived from props.

```
    draggedItemSpec {
        beginDrag(props, monitor, connect)
        {
       /*how do I access component state here? 
Why there is a limitation that when creating dragged object, you should only use props?*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to beginDrag is actually 'component' (per: http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-source.html), which provides access to the instance of the React component that was dropped in to, so within your beginDrag you can actually do

```
draggedItemSpec {
    beginDrag(props, monitor, component)
    {
      const currentState = component.getState();
      // Do things with that state
    }
}
```